# Get SuscriberKey field name that relates to a field in a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, relationships, fields, subscriber-key

So in Marketing Cloud I'm trying to get the field name from a data extension that is the relationship to the SubscriberKey;

E.g. let's say I know the DE customer key and I retrieve all fields via **DataExtensionField** soap API and in that list is one field that is the relationship to the SubscriberKey but it's unknown because it's each DE in our case is variable, where I'm having trouble is getting which field is the relation. In other words how would I get the SubscriberKey/ DE field relationship dynamically?
I hope this makes sense.

In the image attached the **SubID** in this case is the related field but that's never known.
P.S. this is a PHP application.[image]

Answer (score 0):

That value can be found by doing a Retrieve on the DataExtension object, specifying the SendableDataExtensionField.Name property.

Example SOAP:

```
 <RetrieveRequest>
<ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
<Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
<Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
<Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
<Properties>Name</Properties>
<Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
<Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
<Properties>DataRetentionPeriod</Properties>
<Properties>DataRetentionPeriodLength</Properties>
<Properties>RowBasedRetention</Properties>
<Properties>DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod</Properties>
<Properties>Template.CustomerKey</Properties>
<Properties>SendableDataExtensionField.Name</Properties>
<Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
   <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
   <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
   <Value>ExampleKey</Value>
</Filter>
```